# Can Spectacle include information from the taskbar in the screenshot?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, date, kde5

I want to make a screenshot with `Spectacle ( 20.04.0 )` including the date. I tried clicking on the `clock`, which opens the `agenda` and then make a screenshot. When I do that the agenda disappears and the screenshot is made with it. It does not matter if the setting of the `taskbar` is set to 'always visable' or 'hide automaticly'. 
How can I achieve my goal of making the screenshot with the information I want from the taskbar? Or can I make `Spectacle` include a date on the screenshot ( not always, but when I need it ). I have looked through the settings and cannot find anything that looks remotely like this option.
Alternative: Another program to make screenshots which have this option. Can anybody recommend one?
Thanks in advance.
I use:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04.4
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-41-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB